# center vertically the content and absolute position of tcolorbox, tcbraster

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to create a `tcolorbox`, but now I need your help:

1. Centering vertically the content
2. Absolute position of `tcolorbox`: when I change position *x* or *y*

My minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,listings,breakable,listingsutf8,theorems,hooks,fitting]{tcolorbox}%
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
\setcellgapes{12pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tableA/.style={
enhanced,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=blue!10!white,
colframe=green!50!black,
colbacktitle=red!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,fontlower=\itshape] %
{
\makegapedcells
\begin{tcolorbox}[tableA,tabularx*={\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}}{Y|Y|},title={This is a table},boxrule=0.8pt]
A & B          \\\hline
A   & \includegraphics[width = 2cm]{"example-image-a"}   \\\hline
A & AAA  \\\hline
B  & BBB  \\\hline
A   & \includegraphics[width = 2cm]{"example-image-b"} 
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{tcbraster}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple if you load `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and use the option `valign=c` in `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,listings,breakable,listingsutf8,theorems,hooks,fitting]{tcolorbox}%
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
\setcellgapes{12pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tableA/.style={
enhanced,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=blue!10!white,
colframe=green!50!black,
colbacktitle=red!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,fontlower=\itshape] %
{
\makegapedcells
\begin{tcolorbox}[tableA,tabularx*={\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}}{Y|Y|},title={This is a table},boxrule=0.8pt]
A & B          \\\hline
A   & \includegraphics[width = 2cm, valign=c]{"example-image-a"}   \\\hline
A & AAA  \\\hline
B  & BBB  \\\hline
A   & \includegraphics[width = 2cm, valign=c]{"example-image-b"} 
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{tcbraster}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your help. It look beautiful

Comment: When i edit {Y|Y|} => {|Y{2cm}|Y{5cm}|}, the center vertical line between 2 columns is hidden. Please help. https://imgur.com/zfiFj9s

Comment: @tisaigon I have no time at the moment, sorry. Please post another question, someone else will help before me.