# Missing vertical line when insert column width in tabularx

Tags: tabularx

This question is a sequel to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477498/center-vertically-the-content-and-absolute-postion-of-tcolorbox-tcbraster/477512?noredirect=1#comment1205836_477512).

After column width added (`Y{2cm}|Y{5cm}|`), vertical line is missing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,listings,breakable,listingsutf8,theorems,hooks,fitting]{tcolorbox}%
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
\setcellgapes{12pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tableA/.style={
enhanced,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=blue!10!white,
colframe=green!50!black,
colbacktitle=red!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,fontlower=\itshape] %
{
\makegapedcells
\begin{tcolorbox}[tableA,tabularx*={\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}}{Y{2cm}|Y{5cm}|},title={This is a table},boxrule=0.8pt]
A & B          \\\hline
A   & \includegraphics[width = 2cm, valign=c]{"example-image-a"}   \\\hline
A & AAA  \\\hline
B  & BBB  \\\hline
A   & \includegraphics[width = 2cm, valign=c]{"example-image-b"} 
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{tcbraster}


\end{document}
```

How can I get the vertical line?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: The `Y` type column does not take a width argument as you tried to to. This is why your above shown code reslts in the following error message: `Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (2cm):` As usual, it is not worth looking at the 'output'  if you recieve an error message.

Comment: If you want unevenly wide columns, you might be interested in using `>{\hsize=0.56\hsize}Y|>{\hsize=1.44\hsize}Y|` instead. This will result in the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3LV5.png

Comment: @leandriis thank for your solution. And How can i set table width by cm? Thanks

Comment: do you really need `tcbraster`? how many boxes you will have in one row? table width is equal to `tcolorbox` width, but it in your case is defined by `raster width` and `raster columns=` (which you not defined).

Comment: Since you use the `tabularx` mode and columns that derive from the `x` type column, you can only specify their width relative to `\hsize` as shown in my previous comment. If you prefer to specify column widths using cm `tabularx` might not be the best package to use.

Comment: @Zarko thank. it work when definition raster width.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify *relative* widths, you can define `Y` as

```
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

and in the argument you put a decimal number representing the fraction reserved for the column. In the example below, the second column will be three times as wide as the first column. The sum of the factors should equal the number of `X` columns allocated, here two.

Full example, with some reordering of the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% add only the libraries you need
%\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings,breakable,listingsutf8,theorems,hooks,fitting}

\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\setcellgapes{12pt}

\tcbset{
  tableA/.style={
    enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
    colback=blue!10!white,
    colframe=green!50!black,
    colbacktitle=red!40!white,
    coltitle=black,
    center title,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[
  colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  fontlower=\itshape
]{
  \makegapedcells
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    tableA,
    tabularx*={\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}}{Y{0.5}|Y{1.5}},
    title={This is a table},boxrule=0.8pt
  ]
  A & B \\
  \hline
  A & \includegraphics[width = 2cm, valign=c]{"example-image-a"} \\
  \hline
  A & AAA \\
  \hline
  B & BBB \\
  \hline
  A & \includegraphics[width = 2cm, valign=c]{"example-image-b"} 
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{tcbraster}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank so much. tabularX is not too asomwe